# A Tagging System for FAQ Google Sites

Tags: google-drive, google-classic-sites

I'm creating a FAQ for our department, and my first thought was to display it on a Google Sites page. I was also asked to be able to assign tags to each question, so that when I click a button or link or something, all the questions of the desired tag would appear.

I think I have the beginnings of a solution. But I need help with a certain point.

1. Create a Drive folder for each tag (such as Finance, Data, Operations, etc.)
2. Write a separate Google Doc for each question and its answer.
3. Put each Doc into one or more folders. (Since Drive's "folders" are actually labels, you can have a Doc in both Data and Finance, for instance.)
4. On the Sites page, the user sees a list of tags (or the tree of folders or something.)  The user clicks the desired tab.
5. Then a miracle occurs [1](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a2/d1/a1/a2d1a129c5d95edaf01fc4507b3c6787.jpg)
6. ...and links to the those questions appear on the page.

I need to be more explicit in Step 5.

Comment: Maybe you should consider to use Google Groups.

Comment: Why? Does it allow tagging?

Comment: Yes. See https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2645570?hl=en